# Convert a MongoDB dump to JSON

Tags: mongodb

I have inherited an old MongoDB dump file, but it's a `.gz` archive. Is there a way to retreive the data in a human-readable format without requiring to install a mongodb server? I need to extract the data from it, but the original setup no longer exists.

Comment: I don't think so. But installing and running a local mongoDB is just a matter of some Minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
If the mongodump is created with --gzip option you will need to restore it with [mongorestore](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/) --gzip to mongod server to see the content. ( As per @Wernfried suggestion in the comments )

Option 2:
If the mongodump is gzip compressed after it was mongodump-ed , then you can first
gunzip archive.gz , usully mongodump files are stored in BSON format , you can see(extract to JSON) what is in the bson files easily with the [bsondump](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/bsondump/) utility